# PySpark: create new column based on dictionary values matching with string in another column

Tags: python, string, dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe A that looks like this:

| ID | SOME_CODE | TITLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 024df3 | Large garden in New York, New York |
| 2 | 0ffw34 | Small house in dark Detroit, Michigan |
| 3 | 93na09 | Red carpet in beautiful Miami |
| 4 | 8339ct | Skyscraper in Los Angeles, California |
| 5 | 84p3k9 | Big shop in northern Boston, Massachusetts |

I have also another dataframe B:

| City | Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| Los Angeles | LA |
| New York | NYC |
| Miami | MI |
| Boston | BO |
| Detroit | DTW |

I would like to add new "SHORTCUT" column to dataframe A, based on the fact that "Title" column in A contains city from column "City" in dataframe B.
I have tried to use dataframe B as dictionary and map it to dataframe A, but I can't overcome fact that city names are in the middle of the sentence.

The desired output is:

| ID | SOME_CODE | TITLE | SHORTCUT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 024df3 | Large garden in New York, New York | NYC |
| 2 | 0ffw34 | Small house in dark Detroit, Michigan | DTW |
| 3 | 93na09 | Red carpet in beautiful Miami, Florida | MI |
| 4 | 8339ct | Skyscraper in Los Angeles, California | LA |
| 5 | 84p3k9 | Big shop in northern Boston, Massachusetts | BO |

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage [pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function
And see if this helps:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data1={'id':range(5),'some_code':["024df3","0ffw34","93na09","8339ct","84p3k9"],'title':["Large garden in New York, New York","Small house in dark Detroit, Michigan","Red carpet in beautiful Miami","Skyscraper in Los Angeles, California","Big shop in northern Boston, Massachusetts"]}
df1=pd.DataFrame(data=data1)

data2={'city':["Los Angeles","New York","Miami","Boston","Detroit"],"shortcut":["LA","NYC","MI","BO","DTW"]}
df2=pd.DataFrame(data=data2)

# Creating a list of cities.
cities=list(df2['city'].values)

def matcher(x):
  for index,city in enumerate(cities):
    if x.lower().find(city.lower())!=-1:
      return df2.iloc[index]["shortcut"]
  return np.nan

df1['shortcut']=df1['title'].apply(matcher)
print(df1.head())
```

This would generate the following o/p:

```
   id some_code                                       title shortcut
0   0    024df3          Large garden in New York, New York      NYC
1   1    0ffw34       Small house in dark Detroit, Michigan      DTW
2   2    93na09               Red carpet in beautiful Miami       MI
3   3    8339ct       Skyscraper in Los Angeles, California       LA
4   4    84p3k9  Big shop in northern Boston, Massachusetts       BO
```