# Pandas isin() does not return anything even when the keywords exist in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, match, isin

I'd like to search for a list of keywords in a text column and **select all rows where the exact keywords exist.** I know this question has many duplicates, but I can't understand why the solution is not working in my case.

```
keywords = ['fake', 'false', 'lie']
```

df1:

|  | text |
| --- | --- |
| 19152 | I think she is the Corona Virus.... |
| 19154 | Boy you hate to see that. I mean seeing how it was contained and all. |
| 19155 | Tell her it’s just the fake flu, it will go away in a few days. |
| 19235 | Is this fake news? |
| ... | ... |
| 20540 | She’ll believe it’s just alternative facts. |

**Expected results:** I'd like to select rows that have the exact keywords in my list ('fake', 'false', 'lie). For example, in the above df, it should return rows 19155 and 19235.

**str.contains()**

```
df1[df1['text'].str.contains("|".join(keywords))]
```

The problem with **`str.contains()`** is that the result is not limited to the exact keywords. For example, it returns sentences with `believe` (e.g., row 20540) because `lie` is a substring of "believe"!

**pandas.Series.isin**

To find the rows including the exact keywords, I used [pd.Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1[df1.text.isin(keywords)]
#df1[df1['text'].isin(keywords)]
```

Even though I see there are matches in df1, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the data in a text format, rather than using an image?

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/72720147/2986344 (quite similar).
Try a matcher function on dataframe.apply.

Comment: This one can also be helpful, it uses regex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170763/pandas-dataframe-check-if-a-value-exists-using-regex#51170991

Comment: Hi Mona. If you can, please try to avoid adding commentary about the answers in question edits. For the most part, Q and A are chronological: the question is asked, then answers are added afterwards. Thus, the best expression of a question (for your many future readers) is without any references to answers. If you want to comment on answers, comments under the answers may be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If text is as follows,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['text'] = [
    "Dear Kellyanne, Please seek the help of Paula White I believe ...",
    "trump saying it was under controll was a lie, ...",
    "Her mouth should hanve been ... All the lies she has told ...",
    "she'll believe ...",
    "I do believe in ...",
    "This value is false ...",
    "This value is fake ...",
    "This song is fakelove ..."
]
keywords = ['misleading', 'fake', 'false', 'lie']
```

**First,**

Simple way is this.

```
df1[df1.text.apply(lambda x: True if pd.Series(x.split()).isin(keywords).sum() else False)]
```

```
                      text
5  This value is false ...
6   This value is fake ...
```

It'll not catch the words like "believe", but can't catch the words "lie," because of the special letter.

**Second,**

So if remove a special letter in the text data like

```
new_text = df1.text.apply(lambda x: re.sub("[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", " ", x))
df1[new_text.apply(lambda x: True if pd.Series(x.split()).isin(keywords).sum() else False)]
```

Now It can catch the word "lie,".

```
                                                text
1  trump saying it was under controll was a lie, ...
5                            This value is false ...
6                             This value is fake ...
```

**Third,**

It can't still catch the word **lies**. It can be solved by using a library that tokenizes to the same verb from a different forms verb. You can find how to tokenize from here([tokenize-words-in-a-list-of-sentences-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361073/tokenize-words-in-a-list-of-sentences-python)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question (you can now see a subset of my df). Text is a column in df1.

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

df[df.text.apply(lambda x: any(i for i in re.findall('\w+', x) if i in keywords))]
```

Output:

```
                                                text
2  Tell her it’s just the fake flu, it will go aw...
3                                 Is this fake news?
```

Answer (score 1):

I think splitting words then matching is a better and straightforward approach, e.g. if the `df` and `keywords` are

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['lama abc', 'cow def', 'foo bar', 'spam egg']})
keywords = ['foo', 'lama']

df

       text
0  lama abc
1   cow def
2   foo bar
3  spam egg
```

This should return the correct result

```py
df.loc[pd.Series(any(word in keywords for word in words) for words in df['text'].str.findall(r'\w+'))]

       text
0  lama abc
2   foo bar
```

---

#### Explaination

First, do words splitting in `df['text']`

```py
splits = df['text'].str.findall(r'\w+')
```

`splits` is

```py
0    [lama, abc]
1     [cow, def]
2     [foo, bar]
3    [spam, egg]
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Then we need to find if there exists any word in a row should appear in the keywords

```py
# this is answer for a single row, if words is the split list of that row
any(word in keywords for word in words)

# for the entire dataframe, use a Series, `splits` from above is word split lists for every line
rows = pd.Series(any(word in keywords for word in words) for words in splits)
rows

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Now we can find the correct rows with

```py
df.loc[rows]

       text
0  lama abc
2   foo bar
```

Be aware this approach could consume much more memory as it needs to generate the split list on each line. So if you have huge data sets, this might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i upvoted it (liked your detailed explanation). However, it gave me this error: I`ndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)`.

Comment: Also, see @BeRT2me 's answer, her/his answer does the same splitting then matching strategy, but the memory problem is eliminated with a lambda within `.apply`, a better solution.

Comment: @mOna Aha, I think the index problem should occur when index of the dataframe is not integers in order. So BeRT2me 's answer truly is a better version of this approach, it also circumvents that index problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because `pd.Series.isin()` checks if the string is in the column, and not if the string in the column contains a specific word. I just tested this code snippet:

```
s = pd.Series(['lama abc', 'cow', 'lama', 'beetle', 'lama',
               'hippo'], name='animal')

s.isin(['cow', 'lama'])
```

And as I was thinking, the first string, even containing the word 'lama', returns False.

Maybe try using regex? See this: [searching a word in the column pandas dataframe python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49950261/searching-a-word-in-the-column-pandas-dataframe-python)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @lazyer's answer worked :) I'm also checking the link you provided. Thank you!